# about the $\Gamma (x+1)$ product Representation

Tags: calculus

The classical product representation
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma (x)}=x e^{\gamma  x} \prod _{k=1}^{\infty } e^{-\frac{x}{k}} \left(\frac{x}{k}+1\right)$$
and this is faster
$$\Gamma (x+1)=e^{-\left(\gamma  x-\frac{1}{12} x^2 \left(\pi ^2-4 x \zeta (3)\right)\right)} \prod _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{k e^{\frac{x \left(6 k^2-3 k x+2 x^2\right)}{6 k^3}}}{k+x}$$
Mathematica calculate it perfect but where it come from?? from taylor Series

Comment: It can be obtained from the Weierstrass factorization theorem applied to the entire function $$\frac{1}{\Gamma (z + 1)}$$ having zeros at the negative integers. It is more visible if you write the product in the form $$
\frac{1}{{\Gamma (z + 1)}} = \exp \left( {\gamma z - \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{{12}}z^2  + \frac{{\zeta (3)}}{3}z^3 } \right)\prod\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left( {1 + \frac{z}{k}} \right)\exp \left( { - \frac{z}{k} + \frac{{z^2 }}{{2k^2 }} - \frac{{z^3 }}{{3k^3 }}} \right)} .$$